Apostol's Calculus Vol 2, Chapter 1.13, Exercise 2

Suppose we retain the first three axioms for a real inner product
(symmetry, linearity, and homogeneity but replace the fourth axiom by
a new axiom ($4'$): $(x, x) = 0$ if and only if $x = O$. Prove that
either $(x, x) > 0$ for all $x \neq O$ or else $(x, x) < 0$ for all $x
 \neq O$.
[Hint: Assume $(x, x) > 0$ for some $x \neq 0$ and $(y, y) < 0$ for
some $y \neq O$. In the space spanned by {$x, y$}, find an element $z
 \neq O$ with $(z, z) = 0$.]

For context, the axioms for the inner product of a real linear space from the book is as follows (p.14):

DEFINITION. A real linear space $V$ is said to have an inner product if for each pair of
elements $x$ and $y$ in $V$ there corresponds a unique real number $(x, y)$ satisfying the following axioms for all choices of $x, y, z$ in $V$ and all real scalars $c$.
(1) $(x, y) = (y, x)$ (commutativity, or symmetry).
(2) $(x, y + z) = (x,y) + (x, z)$ (distributivity, or linearity).
(3) $c(x, y) = (cx,y)$ (associativity, or homogeneity).
(4) $(x, x) > 0$ if $x \neq O$ (positivity).

Following Apostol's hint, my understanding is that we should assume $(x, x) > 0$ for some $x \neq O$ and $(y, y) < 0$ for some $y \neq O$ and then somehow find an element $z
 \neq O$ with $(z, z) = 0$, thus contradicting axiom $(4')$. Here is what I have so far:

Suppose we have $(x, x) > 0$ for some $x \neq O$ and $(y, y) < 0$
for some $y \neq O$. Let $S = \{x, y \}$ and let $z$ be some element
in the span of $S$, $z \neq O$. $\implies z = c_1x+ c_2y$   where
$c_1, c_2$ are not both $0$.
We have: $(z,z) = (c_1x+ c_2y, c_1x+ c_2y) = (c_1x + c_2y, c_1x) + (c_1x+c_2y, c_2y) = (c_1x, c_1x) + (c_1x, c_2y) + (c_2y, c_1x) + (c_2y, c_2y)$ $ = c_1^2(x,x) + c_2^2(y,y) + 2c_1c_2(x,y)$

This is where I'm currently stuck on. My idea is to find a pair of $c_1$ and $c_2$ in order to make to expression equal to $0$ but I have no idea how to do that. I am losing sleep over this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Choosing for instance $c_2=1$, you want to prove the existence of some solution $c_1=c\in\Bbb R$ of the quadratic equation
$$(x,x)c^2+2(x,y)c+(y,y)=0.$$
Just notice that
$$\Delta:=[2(x,y)]^2-4(x,x)(y,y)>0.$$
